# Can the "edits improved" stat be added to the more info box on a review?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

At the moment the "more" info box displays the following stats:

[image]

But the number of edits a user has improved isn't displayed.

Could this stat also be shown? Since the **more** box is for displaying the reviewers' decisions, so why not display *all* the decision stats? I personally would find it interesting to see how many users actually bother to edit an edit<sup>1</sup>.

Maybe something like,

[image]

<sup>1 (helps to better diagnose the spread of Robous-Reviewiticus)</sup>.

Comment: +1, but: Some people don´t want to improve posts *because* of robo-accepts would be faster in the meantime and rolling back everytime etc. gets on the nerves

Comment: AFAIK edits are included in the accepts and rejections (depending on whether the suggestion was marked helpful). The suggested change would make it look as if they are completely separate category.

Comment: I like the suggestion and I would also add the number of edits the Reviewer has made along with the percentage (or number) accepted. That might start to clutter things up a bit, but it would be very interesting.

Comment: @ouflak Well I guess that's the reason they added an option to display more info (to avoid clutter), since the default view is only the reviewers' decision on that particular review (screenshot minus the red box).

Comment: Shouldn't this be on MSE instead of MSO?